# Floating voltage creation

Tags: circuit-design

I would like to create a floating voltage ( about 12-15Volts).
This voltage will be used as a supply for an optocoupler.
This voltage should not be referenced to ground. Must be completely floating.

What are some ways to create this floating voltage that I can connect it later on any circuit that I want?

Currently, I use a transformer for creating this floating voltage due to the isolation between the primary and the secondary.

Is there a way of creating a floating voltage from a ground voltage reference?

Are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: Battery, motor -> plastic shaft -> generator, lamp -> air space -> photo voltaic cell, air blower -> plastic pipe -> air turbine -> generator are alternatives, but the transformer has a lot of advantages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mean with an ic circuit or another topology that I will provide a voltage and it will generate o floating voltage

Comment: Why do you need to drive the optocoupler with an isolated power? The output from the optocoupler will already be isolated.

Comment: @pipe I will use the voltage from the secondary side of the transformer as power to the secondary side of the optocoupler so that I can control with a PWM a floating voltage. Can you think of another way controlling a floating voltage?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get a floating power voltage is to use a power module with isolated output.  That's what they do.  There are many available.

You say the output needs to be 12 to 15 V, but you need to specify the current (or power) too.  You also need to specify what input voltage is available.  For example, are you going to make the isolated 12 V from 120 VAC 60 Hz, a internal 24 V DC supply, something else?

For any significant power, the isolation will be done with a transformer one way or another.  The transformer can be part of a switching power supply that runs it at high frequency, or something that runs directly from 50 or 60 Hz line voltage.  Most isolated power modules, like I mentioned above, have a transformer in them.

For small amounts of power, other isolation techniques are possible.  A capacitive charge pump can be appropriate, especially if the voltage across the isolation barrier doesn't change much.

Another option is light shining on a solar panel.  That would be terribly inefficient, but for small amounts of power that may not matter.  Two advantages of this technique are very high isolation voltages and low capacitance across the isolation barrier are possible.

Comment: For even smaller amount of output power you can get the "light shining on a solar panel" equivalent [in an IC](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/product/opto/photocoupler/photovoltaic-output.html). That is, if there's anything you can do with 20 µA.